# how to add the loading screen in to tab in android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

In my application i'm using two tabs one tab app contacts and other one is all contacts ,in application opening a one tab to other one it tack 10sce ,in that time how to add the same type of message like loading screen etc ,

plz tell me how to do that in my android app?

```
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabview);



    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 



    TextView txtTab = new TextView(this);
    txtTab.setText("Mobell Contacts");
    txtTab.setPadding(8, 9, 8, 9);
    txtTab.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    txtTab.setTextSize(14);
    //txtTab.setTypeface(localTypeface1);
    txtTab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);


    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(txtTab).setContent(new Intent(this, ContactList.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    tabHost.addTab(spec);






    TextView txtTab1 = new TextView(this);
    txtTab1.setText("All Contacts");
    txtTab1.setPadding(8, 9, 8, 9);
    txtTab1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    txtTab1.setTextSize(14);
    //txtTab.setTypeface(localTypeface1);
    txtTab1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);


    TabHost.TabSpec spec1;
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator(txtTab1).setContent(new Intent(this, TabAct2.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    tabHost.addTab(spec1);



    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#101010"));
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#848284"));





    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
            {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#848284"));

            }
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#181418"));   


        }
    });





}




   }
```

see this code plz tell how to add the progressDialog when tab change one to other...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this for showing progress -

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        Button b;
        ProgressBar pb1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            pb1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            }

        public void click(View v){
            new Thread("thread1"){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(4000);
                            pb1.setProgress(i*10);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                };
            }.start();  
        }
    }
```

In case you want to show a message, use Spinner.

Comment: thanks for replay , where i went to put this code in  TabActivity are other else

Comment: please put this code in Tab Click activity. Check if this works fine

Comment: in setOnTabChangedListener i add this

Comment: @AnilMH have you solved your problem or not? without solved don't accept the answer.. others will suffer by your wrong accepting

Comment: @AnilMH then why you accept the answer..If you accept it you won't get other more good answers

Comment: @AnilMH Please do a work around before you accept answers. This will create confusions while others check for proper answers. Also, you wont get right answers for your Questions

Comment: @Lohit That's why i told to AnilMH he is not understanding and not do a work around on it

Answer (score 0):

Show progressbar on center of screen using visibility on/off

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `TabActivity` (and you haven't posted your work around yet), so, I am guessing you have used

1. `TabActivity`
2. `Activity` (for both tabs)

Now, when you switch from one tab to another you are actually calling `Activity`. So, just create an `AsyncTask` in the `Activity` which takes time to load. For instance,

```
class ContactLoadAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "title", "loading", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // call your contact loading functions here

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }

}
```

And, call this `AsyncTask` in `onCreate()` of your `Activity`.

`new ContactLoadAsync().execute();`